# Google Script - Sheets - Sorting Multiple Sheets - Not working right

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

To whom it may concern,
I am running into issues where I have multiple sheets in a workbook.  Two of which are:
"Stage Crew" and
"Stage Crew Points"

I am trying to sort BOTH in my script after adding a row to each.
The sort seems to be messing up my data on "Stage Crew Points".
I suspect the selection of the sheet PRIOR to sorting may be related.

Could someone look at my code and give me some suggestions?
This is AFTER the new row is added to the 2 sheets separately.
Those parts of the code seem to be working well.
It is just on the sort, that it gets goofed up.

```
  /***********************************************/
  //  Stage Crew
  // Sort Ascending by Last Name, then First Name
  /***********************************************/      
  // Column A = Last Name         // Column B = First Name        
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Stage Crew'), true);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var lastcol = ss.getLastColumn();
  // Try combining the sort with the Activate...
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrow -1, lastcol).activate().sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);  
  // Select A1, so not all highlighted
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).activate();   
  
  /***********************************************/
  //  Stage Crew Points
  // Sort Ascending by Last Name, then First Name
  /***********************************************/      
  /* 1/26/21 - For some reason the SORT is still not working right. 
     Seems to be sorting only the col A - L, not M - END 
  */
  // Column A = Last Name         // Column B = First Name        
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName('Stage Crew Points'), true);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow   = getBORDERRowByColumnArray(sheet_PointsList);  
  var lastcol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  /* JS 1/26/21 Above */
  // Try combining the sort with the Activate...
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastrow -2 , lastcol).activate().sort([{column: 1, ascending: true}, {column: 2, ascending: true}]);  
  // Select A1, so not all highlighted
  sheet.getRange(1, 1).activate();
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What does this line do `var lastrow   = getBORDERRowByColumnArray(sheet_PointsList);`? Moreover, I was able to successfully run your code - so my hunch is that the error stems from somewhere else. Is this in the same script and in the same function? Are you manually selecting another sheet?

Comment: Thank you. All good. The getBORDERRowByColumnArray(sheet_PointsList); was used to find a particular row on the sheet that I need to limit my sort range to.  I did discover the problem.  It had to do with formulas that were pointing to another sheet.  When that other sheet was sorted, it automatically changed the values on the Points sheet.  So i decided to separate those formulas and freezeValues after assigning the data PRIOR to sorting.